# fortranの文番号のエラー

Tags: fortran

お世話になります。
gfortranを使ってfortranのコードを書いているのですが以下の部分でエラーになってしまいます。

```
  200          format('size:',2I3,' hot(0)/cold(1):',I2,
  &  ' Therm:',I5,' Int:',I5,' NConf:',I5,'h:', F6.2)
```

出力はこうなっています。

```
  253 |       200          format('size:',2I3,' hot(0)/cold(1):',I2,
      |       1
Error: Invalid character in name at (1)
test.f:254:7:

  254 |       &  ' Therm:',I5,' Int:',I5,' NConf:',I5,'h:', F6.2)
      |       1
Error: Invalid character in name at (1)
test.f:251:72:

  251 |      &, getExternalMagnetFiled()
      |                                                                        1
Error: FORMAT label 200 at (1) not defined
```

ネットでも調べてみましたが, なかなか解決法がわかりません。
解決法をご存知の方教えてください。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

おそらくfortran77の固定形式によるエラーですね。
boundary conditionさんが文頭を何カラム目にしたかわかりませんが, 最初の200を7カラム目よりも左にして, &を6カラム目にいれてみてください。
こちらの環境下で試してみましたがうまくいきました。

以下試したコード：

```
!テストコード
      program test

      write(*,200) 316, 23, 15, 12345,12345, 12345, 311.25
200   format('size:',2I3,' hot(0)/cold(1):',I2,
     &' Therm:',I5,'Int:',I5,' NConf:',I5,'h:', F6.2)
       end program
```